# getting strange labels in a DataFrame out of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Jupyter Notebook as well as in Sublime Text I get a strange labeling of the Columns.

1. I created a cartesian product
2. Out of that I created a dictionary and from there a DataFrame

My code is as follows:

```
import itertools
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

given_list = ["+","-"]
given_length_of_combinations = 3

cartesian_product = itertools.product(given_list, repeat=given_length_of_combinations)
```

The output for the cartesian product is this:

```
[('+', '+', '+'), ('+', '+', '-'), ('+', '-', '+'), ('+', '-', '-'), ('-', '+', '+'), ('-', '+', '-'), ('-', '-', '+'), ('-', '-', '-')]
```

```
a = dict.fromkeys(cartesian_product,("+","-"))

new_frame = pd.DataFrame(a)

print(new_frame)
```

my output is

```
   +           -         
   +     -     +     -   
   +  -  +  -  +  -  +  -
0  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
1  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

Can someone explain, why the column labels don't match with the tuple values?
How can I change that?

Comment: They do, it is just the representation that is different. Print `new_frame.columns`

Comment: I've seen that. But I was wondering about the displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

> We’ve “sparsified” the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes. Note that how the index is displayed can be controlled using the multi_sparse option in pandas.set_options():

So if display real levels:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(new_frame)

   +  +  +  +  -  -  -  -
   +  +  -  -  +  +  -  -
   +  -  +  -  +  -  +  -
0  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
1  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```